# Calculate the 30th and 60th percentiles of X.

Tags: probability, random-variables, percentile

The following function is the CDF of a mixed distribution 
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}
0,& \text{when }x<0\\ 
\frac{x+1}{8},&\text{when } 0≤x<1\\ 
\frac{x+3}{8},&\text{when } 1≤x<3\\ 
1,&\text{when } x≥3.
\end{cases}$$
Calculate $X_{0.3}$ and $X_{0.6}$, the 30th and 60th percentiles of $X$, if $X$ is a r.v. with $F(x)$ given above.

So far, I only calculated the 60th percentile as follows:
\begin{align} X_{0.6} &= F^{-1}(3/5)\\
              \frac{x + 3}{8} &= \frac35\\
              x+3 &= \frac{24}5,\end{align}
so $x = 9/5$.

I know I have to solve $X_{0.30} = F^{-1}(3/10)$, but I do not know which piece of the definition of $F$ to use because no piece produces values that would include $0.3$ in their range.

Can anyone help me calculate this percentile? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Percentiles are really nice when $F$ is invertible and the distribution is continuous. In this example, the distribution is not continuous; it is mixed. That means you have to check point masses.
\begin{align*}
F(1-)&=\lim_{x\to 1^-}F(x)=0.25\\
F(1)&=0.5
\end{align*}
This tells us that $\mathbb{P}(X=1)=0.25$. That means that the 30$^{\text{th}}$ percentile is at $x=1$, or
\begin{equation*}
\pi_{0.3}=1
\end{equation*}
Note that you could have other percentile values also being $1$, say $\pi_{0.35}=1$ too!

Answer (score 0):

It spends $25\%$ of the time below $1$; and $50\%$ of the time above $1$, so it spends $25\%$ of the time with the exact value $1$.

Just as the median of a list of numbers is the middle one, although several other numbers may have that value, the $30^{th}$ percentile is exactly $1$, as $25\%$ of the numbers are below it and at least $5\%$ of the numbers are equal to it.